# JavaScript or Python library for getting customers data from NSE NMF (National Stock Exchange)

Tags: javascript, python

We have some investor details at the NSE-NMF India portal, https://www.nsenmf.com/. Are there any REST APIs or libraries to get these details programatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find an existing library, so implemented a new JavaScript based library, https://github.com/sarthakj178/nse-nmf

### Install using the following

```
npm install --save nse-nmf
```

### Usage for getting Customers and Customer Details

```
const nse = require('nse-nmf');

nse.getCustomers({
  userId: "MFS*****", 
  password: "****", 
  brokerCode: "ARN-*****"
}).then((customers) => {
        console.log(customers.map((customer) => {
          return {
            customerId: customer.customerId,
            investorName: customer.investorName
          }
        });
});

nse.getCustomerDetails({
  userId: "MFS*****", 
  password: "****", 
  brokerCode: "ARN-*****"
}, "123412341234").then((customer) => {
    console.log(customer.customerId, customer.investorName, customer.dateOfBirth, customer.emailAddress, customer.mobileNo);
})
```